# Excel 2013: Adding a formula / function to a chart legend

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have a chart in Excel with three legend entries. Each of them contains the word "Umsatz" and all of them are linked to cell values. Now I would like to remove that word from the entries with a function since it's also the title of my chart. However, I can't and don't want to edit the cell values accordingly.

So I right-clicked the legend, clicked on "select data" and then tried to edit a legend entry and enter a formula to replace the word with nothing but it doesn't accept it claiming the formula might be wrong or whatever.

When I try the same forumla in a cell in my worksheet it works fine.

```
=SUBSTITUTE('00000_Musterkunde'!Z5S1;"Umsatz ";"")
```

Am I doing something wrong or does Excel really not accept formulas in chart legends?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

mariu5, please take a look at [How to Show a Formula Result in an Excel Chart Legend](http://www.consultdmw.com/excel-chart-legend.htm), HTH.
The point is, you need to create first the formulas in the cells of the table, then you can reference to them!

> Here is one way of making your legend follow the years in row 1 and
>   the averages in row 14.
>
> First of all, create this formula in a blank cell, eg. A17:
>
> =TEXT(B1,"0000")&" - Average "&TEXT(B14,"0.00")
>
> Then create this formula in say A18:
>
> =TEXT(C1,"0000")&" - Average "&TEXT(C14,"0.00")
>
> These two formulae generate the legend you want to achieve, making use
>   of the TEXT function to determine the formatting of the numbers
>   involved.
>
> Now go to your chart and choose the Source Data command from the Chart
>   menu. In the Source Data dialog box, make sure the Series tab is
>   selected.
>
> Select the first series in the Series list. Click the Collapse Dialog
>   button to the right of the Name box. Click on cell A17 in the
>   worksheet. Click the Collapse Dialog button again to return to the
>   Source Data dialog box. Repeat the process for your second series
>   and you should have a legend that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I found the same post along my research and it seems like there is no other way I guess. I wanted to avoid this solution though and tried putting my function directly into the input box where you can choose your cell with the text for the legend entry. Thanks for the help! I think I just write my desired text directly into the legend.